# Build error in Azure CI pipeline as some projects are in different repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am very new in Azure Devops. All my repositories are in BitBucket. I have one project say A which has dependency in project B
In Visual Studio there are no build errors, but when I am building the CI pipeline for A I am getting an error saying "Project B not found"

The CI pipeline is created with repository of project A. How can I solve this?

Note: I am using dev.azure.com and selected "Use classic editor to create a pipeline without YAML" so I am not able to add yaml code. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are those projects in same solution and repo ? If no then you need to create a artifact of the dependancy and pass it to the project A. Also can you share your configuration of classic editor.

Comment: The sln file for project A contains project B but they are in different repository

Comment: Your build pipeline will be pointing to single repo at a time. You need to create a artifact for other repo and then pass that to the current pipeline.

Comment: If you want you can add other project as a submodule or subtree. That way you can achieve it

Comment: Can you provide me some links or example? This will be really helpful 

Comment: I am using dev.azure.com and selected "Use classic editor to create a pipeline without YAML" so I am not able to add yaml code. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I think you dont need to do anything in build pipeline once you add other repo as a submodule in your bitbucket code. Try to do that then no need to do anything special in pipeline. For your reference https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to [check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout) for example like this:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyBitbucketRepoA
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitbucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitbucketOrgOrUser/MyBitbucketRepoA
  - repository: MyBitbucketRepoB
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitbucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitbucketOrgOrUser/MyBitbucketRepoB

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyBitbucketRepoA
- checkout: MyBitbucketRepoB
```

Comment: I am using dev.azure.com and selected "Use classic editor to create a pipeline without YAML" so I am not able to add yaml code. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible at all in classic pipelines.
If it's possible for you, I recommend changing to use YAML-defined pipelines; they offer a lot more control and power over your pipeline.